# usercontrol button bang on press

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way, in a usercontrol, to make a button turns a bool property to true and right after to false, in like one frame.

```
<Button x:Name="Button" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

I'm trying this but of course it is not the solution :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BeatReset= true;
    BeatReset= false;
 }
```

Comment: Assuming the `BeatReset` setter raises a `PropertyChanged` or similar event, yes, that works. However, WPF doesn't really work in terms of 'frames', so it's not clear what you want to accomplish with this. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: If I do BeatReset = true, the property will stay true. But I can't find a way to immediatly turn it back to false, inside the UserControl code.

Comment: `ButtonReset = false;` will immediately set it back to false (unless your property setter is doing something very strange). What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: Even what is the situation for this need is not very clear!

Comment: I wish to achieve a "bang" button. Which stay true only one frame, as soon as I press it, it output true then false right away. I think it is not working because I'm using this usercontrol at runtime and the property stay at 0 all the time. Maybe it changes to fast and some frames get lost.

Comment: Why don't you `wait` for about 1 frame? `await Task.Delay(20)` would probably suffice.

Comment: Or just subscribe to [`CompositionTarget.Rendering`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering(v=vs.110).aspx), set it to false, and unsubscribe.

Comment: What about using the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events separately? It wouldn't be using 'frames' but it might give the desired effect to the user `Button_MouseDown(…) { BeatReset = true; }`, `Button_MouseUp(…) { BeatReset = false; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can set it to true in the button click, then set to false after one frame, as required, using [`CompositionTarget.Rendering`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering(v=vs.110).aspx) event
which occurs just before the objects in the composition tree are rendered. i.e. once per frame.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BeatReset= true;
    CompositionTarget.Rendering += Rendering;
}

private void Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e){
    BeatReset = false;
    CompositionTarget.Rendering -= Rendering;
}
```

So you queue the `BeatReset` set to false in the next frame and get rid of the event handler right after you are done.